# Array Push uses the same index for the same value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I just found out that using the function array.push(value) using the same value name, will give the same index of the first item with the same value name.

Look at the example code following:

```
<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    fruits.push("Orange");
var orange_index = fruits.indexOf("Orange");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = orange_index;
}
</script>
```

If you run it, you will notice that the answer is "1" , that corrisponds to the first "Orange" item inserted into the array.

How can I avoid this behaviour ? I need to insert the same values into an array with different indexes.

Do I need to use multidimensional array ?
I have a deck of cards, and I need to store the ranks and suits in array. So far I created two different arrays for ranks and suits, but I'm having this problem. I retrieve the ranks and suits separately, should I push them together into a new multidimensional array? how ?

Thanks

Comment: This is how your code looks http://jsfiddle.net/40vsmeyt/. Let me know what you are trying

Comment: it doesn't work on jsfiddle. I tried it on w3schools

Comment: push returns the new length of the array so the index of the item is just the (length-1)

Answer (score 1):

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40vsmeyt/2/)**.

> The **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Your array looks like following after you clicking in button :

```
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Orange"]
```

So when you try :

```
var orange_index = fruits.indexOf("Orange");
```

That will return the first index of `Orange` like you saw in description, so normally it will return `1`.

Comment: How do you expect from the javascript to know that you mean second `Orange` and not the first ?

Comment: You're completely right. So how can i solve this problem ? If you check the last part of my question, I explain my real problem

Comment: Ok please try to update your question and clarify more with an example ?

Comment: I'll create a new question because I changed the way I was doing it; I'm using objects now and actually I need to find that index.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.lastIndexOf()` instead of `.indexOf()`, and it will get the last (most recently added) one instead of always the first.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40vsmeyt/3/)

Comment: How you expect that he want always the last.

Comment: Assuming op is able to grasp the concept of distinct values to keep the integrity of the array.  If not, I would then suggest keeping the array values distinctive, but this would need to be done using more functionality.  Op didn't clarify, he just wanted the index of the most recently added item.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify it, but I don't need the last index item.  (anyway thanks for the suggestion, It will be useful in the future) . I explained the real problem in the last part of the question

Comment: @koo27 Then you may want to consider creating your own `push` function that will remove existing values with the same name before appended to the array.

Comment: @RealWorldCoder actually I can't remove the other existing values with the same name, because they represent a deck of cards. So I think I may use a multidimensional array with ranks and suits, am I right ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  What is the array actually storing data for?

Comment: I'm trying to create a card game and I have to store all the cards on the table, taken from the player and in the player hand. I created the deck and two arrays with ranks and suits. I need to use these arrays all over the game. When I need to delete a specific card (rank and suit) from the two arrays I found this problem of the index. So i'm thinking to make a new multidimensional array with the rank and suit together (so I think I can refer to a specific index , right ? ).

Comment: Why wouldn't you either a) make a seperate array of taken cards, or b) make an array for each player?